# Downgrade Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, downgrade

I updated Jenkins a few days ago. But in the current Jenkins version, there are some annoying bugs. Is it possible to downgrade the version of Jenkins and if this is possible, how is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Downgrading should be equivalent to the upgrading process:

> To upgrade from earlier versions of Jenkins, simply redeploy the WAR
>   file. Read [this document](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Containers) for more about container-specific
>   instructions on how to do this. See [this document](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Automated+Upgrade) for automation.

Comment: No, downgrade process is not same as upgrade..there are many configuration changes that needs to be checked.  Simply redeploying the war file does not work.

Answer (score 9):

I have been struggling with downgrading Jenkins as well, lately because the latest version seems to have a problem handling JDK 5 code (which I am unfortunately tied to for a little while longer)

Here's how I did my downgrade:

1. Locate an earlier stable version at https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/
2. Download the war file
3. Stop the Jenkins service
4. Replace the `jenkins.war` with the new.
5. Restart the service.

I had an additional issue with the configuration file not being compatible. E.g. In my case I had to disable matrix to get the service running. Your case may be different, so I suggest another question.

Comment: "Replace the jenkins.war with the new." - where is this `jenkins.war` to be replaced? Considering I'm using Red Hat and ran Jenkins with `service jenkins start`

Comment: I believe you should locate your jenkins install directory. The .war file is located at the top-level directory where jenkins was installed in my system.

Answer (score 8):

I easily rolled back to the last working version by doing below steps:

1. Go to the location where jenkins is installed.
2. Rename `jenkins.war` if it exists to `jenkins.war.corrupted`
3. You would find a file `jenkins.war.bak` in same directory. Rename it to 'jenkins.war'

Comment: It is working fine by doing this but the service is still stopped but UI is accessible now

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I followed the process below -

```
Download the jenkins.war file from https://updates.jenkins-ci.org
Stop the Jenkins service
Replace the jenkins.war with the new.
Restart the service.
Done
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have upgraded from front end (i.e. `Manage Jenkins > Upgrade Jenkins`) Then you will get an option to Downgrade also from there (under Manage Jenkins -- restore to previous version)