# How can I downgrade jenkins from version 2.7.4 to 1.580.3 version?

Tags: jenkins, downgrade

What I am doing is just replacing the jenkins.war file with the older version...anything else which needs to be changed ?

I am trying to downgrade from version 2.7.4 to 1.580.3 , but i am getting loads of errors while just redeploying the war file...I think there are some other changes need to be checked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Downgrade Jenkins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30975866/downgrade-jenkins)

Comment: Duplicate ticket didn't help. There is no proper answer mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

to downgrade jenkins you should follow the equivalent steps to the upgrading process for additional information look at this link

http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2016/06/upgrade-jenkins-and-plugins/